# Override robots.txt exclusion to allow Mediapartners-Google for AdSense

Tags: web-crawlers, google-adsense, robots.txt

I use robots.txt to block all robots.txt compliant bots from a directory like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /sub/*
```

How can I override this so to allow Mediapartners-Google (AdSense) to /sub/?

Comment: You don't need the `*` on your `Disallow` rule.   `Disallow: /sub/` is equivalent because robots.txt rules are "starts with" rules.   Using the `*` is fine for Googlebot, but many robots don't support it and those bots will see it as a literal star.  Your rule is more widely understood without the star.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this at the top of the robots.txt works:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
```

N.B. you may need AdSense to download your robots.txt again, which I believe they do on a 24hr basis.